# Java LibGDX - Drawing a sprite multiple times or creating a new sprite?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, sprite

The first thing that comes to mind for an example is Tic-Tac-Toe. The X's and O's are drawn more than once or a side scroller that uses the same sprite for the ground, sand, or sky. Another example would be two players/actors/mobs that use the same sprite.

What I am trying to do is find a better way than just doing this:

```
//TheGame.java

//Load textures...

ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;
sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

//add sprites to array

batch.begin();
    sprites.get(0).setPosition(0, 0);
    sprites.get(0).draw(batch);
    sprites.get(1).setPosition(0, 0);
    sprites.get(1).draw(batch);
    sprites.get(2).setPosition(200, 0);
    sprites.get(2).draw(batch);
    sprites.get(1).setPosition(400, 0);
    sprites.get(1).draw(batch);
    sprites.get(2).setPosition(200, 200);
    sprites.get(2).draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

I don't want to be setting the positions here. I do actually but not this way.

So I was thinking of something like this instead:

```
//Util.java

static class SpriteIndex{
    public int index, x, y;

    public SpriteIndex(int index, int x, int y){
        this.index = index;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then put that in an array like a queue (I didn't actually use a queue):

```
    //TheGame.java

    ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;
    sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

    ArrayList<SpriteIndex> index;
    index = new ArrayList<SpriteIndex>();

    index.add(new SpriteIndex(0, 0, 0));
    index.add(new SpriteIndex(1, 0, 0));
    index.add(new SpriteIndex(2, 200, 0));
    index.add(new SpriteIndex(1, 400, 0));
    index.add(new SpriteIndex(2, 200, 200));

    sprites.addAll(Util.Load(filenames, 3));
}

@Override
public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++){
        sprites.get(index.get(i).index).setPosition(index.get(i).x, index.get(i).y);
        sprites.get(index.get(i).index).draw(batch);
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

Now I can add to the queue in my input handlers.

If it was done this way you could have a queue for each layer:

```
backGround
midGround
foreGround
fog
overLay
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Instead of using ArrayList you could use the [libgdx Array class](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html)

Comment: @donfuxx I didn't know of that. Thanks. I have already changed that code so much, but the question still stands.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your solution? I'd try to push logic into `SpriteIndex`, getting rid of that index, let it draw itself.

Comment: @StefanHanke That sounds like what I did. I have a Logic class that handles the moving and drawing of the different layers as well as checks to make sure that we are not drawing a sprite that won't be seen because of the foreground.

Comment: Why don't you just make a separate Sprite for each object you're going to draw? It's not a very heavy object. For example, if there are two clouds that use the same region from a texture atlas, you would have two sprites, each with its own position. Then you only have to modify sprite positions when the individual objects move.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You made me realize something. I thought that the texture information (pixels and whatnot) was stored in the `Sprite` object. I see now that that is not the case which was the point (mostly) of my question. I'm sorry I am learning this the hard way, but I am learning none the less.